# Absolute positioned element problem in a relative box with border to one side

Tags: html, css

I have 2 relative boxes at 50% width, inside those boxes are relative divs with background color at 100% width, one with border-right and one with border left. I have an absolute positioned button in the box with border right which overflows the content due to the border. How do I get the absolute positioned button to ignore the border and respect the background color of the div it sits within?

There is no option but to have the button as an absolute element as it needs to stick to the bottom of the box.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#width-100 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrap-50 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 262px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-right: 20px solid #fff;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 262px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-left: 20px solid #fff;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='width-100'>

  <div class='wrap-50'>
    <div class='left'>
      Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text.
      <button class='button'>click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='wrap-50'>
    <div class='right'>
      Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want the absolute button to lie within the background color of the left hand side box and ignore the white border to the right of it.

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/t5ajrw3e/

Comment: give your button a `left: 0`

Comment: It seems your approach is overly complicated. Can you show a picture of your desired result?

Comment: @dhe that works to center the button but the padding of the parent element is missing.

Comment: @connexo I can't add an image here but basically I want the button to have the padding of parent element and be centered at the bottom of the parent div.

Comment: You don't need to use `position:absolute` - flexbox could do that.

Comment: However, you haven't told the button where to be. `right:0` should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply fix the button to the bounds of the parent container whose position is relative.

just add `left:0` and `right:0` along with `bottom:0` to your button.

```
.button {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    background:#000; 
    font-size:12pt;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its positioned absolute, you can set `right: 0;` and that should do it, but it seems like you have set button to have a width of 100% which will make it occupy the whole container, and if you don't want that you can remove the width or set a desired width for the button, and in-case you want to center the button within the parent container, you should indeed look for better solution using `flex` etc.

hope that helps.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#width-100 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrap-50 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 262px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-right: 20px solid #fff;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 262px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-left: 20px solid #fff;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='width-100'>

  <div class='wrap-50'>
    <div class='left'>
      Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text.
      <button class='button'>click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='wrap-50'>
    <div class='right'>
      Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with flexbox. Floating and positioning is the "old way" to do this.

```css
#width-100 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrap-50 {
  flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 20px); /* 20px space between wrap-50 */
  background: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 262px;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='width-100'>

  <div class='wrap-50'>
    Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text.
    <button class='button'>click me</button>
  </div>

  <div class='wrap-50'>
    Hello, this is some test text.<br /> Hello, this is some test text.<br /> Hello, this is some test text.
    <br /> Hello, this is some test text.<br /> Hello, this is some test text.<br /> Hello, this is some test text.<br />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are up for using flexbox then you may refactor as follows:

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  align-self: flex-end; /* added: child flex item of .left */
  transform: translateX(-20px); /* added: move left same width as the container border */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  display: flex; /* added */
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 262px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-right: 20px solid #fff;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

[Fork of your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fpb7zxy/)

Answer (score 0):

Go with the flex my friend, easier to control and cleaner code ;)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 48%;
  min-height: 262px;
  min-width: 262px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='box'>
    <p>
      Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text. Hello, this is some test text.</p>
    <button class='button'>click me</button>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
    <p>
      Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/> Hello, this is some test text.<br/>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```